# Cómo acceder a una clase desde un módulo laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, clase, datatable, livewire

usando [laravel livewire modules](https://github.com/mhmiton/laravel-modules-livewire) creé una tabla, dicha tabla se encuentra en el módulo "Admin", específicamente en `namespace Modules\Admin\Http\Livewire\Tables;`, para inicializar la tabla necesito especificar el modelo con el que va a trabajar, sin embargo, el IDE no lo está "detectando" y cuando la inserto manualmente, el módulo se queja que no encuentra la clase en un directorio que no es el requerido por mí

error:

```
Error
Class "App\Models\LocationGroup" not found (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/livewire/datatables/datatable.blade.php)
```

sin embargo, la clase que yo necesito se encuentra en `App\Models`, es decir, fuera del módulo, cómo podría acceder a ella?

así es como intento importarla, pero el IDE lo marca como clase no encontrada

```
use App\Models\LocationGroup;

class LocationsGroupsTable extends LivewireDatatable
{
    public $model = LocationGroup::class;
```

**dato**: la clase User sí la encuentra y además funciona correctamente

el modelo LocationGroup es:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class LocationGroup extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'locations_groups';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'state'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    use SoftDeletes;

    public function locationGroupLocation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LocationGroupLocation::class, 'group_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el namespace que tiene declarado la clase LocationGroup?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ namespace App\Models, actualicé la pregunta con el modelo

Comment: Parece ok. Prueba correr `composer dump-autoload` para que vuelva a cargar todas las clases

Comment: volví a crear la clase, copiando y pegando el mismo código y funcionó, no sé qué pudo haber sido, el IDE sigue sin "detectarla" pero al menos ya funciona